# Laravel run factory in Tinker

Tags: laravel, factory, laravel-artisan, tinker

I run `Message::factory()->count(10)->create()` in Tinker but get the following error. Any ideas?

> PHP Error:  Call to undefined function Database\Factories\factory() in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-chat-app\database\factories\MessageFactory.php
> on line 22

```
class MessageFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            "subject" => $this->faker->sentence(6),
            "user_id" => function() {
                return factory(App\Models\User::class)->create()->id;
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the closure you've set for `user_id` - it's still using the old factory syntax with the global helper.

```php
return [
    'subject' => $this->faker->sentence(6),
    'user_id' => App\Models\User::factory(),
];
```

Note that you can just return the factory instance (don't need to use a closure, or create/return a user ID) - and it will lazily create the model and associate it if/when required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a fully qualified namespace when using tinker.

Try this:

```
App\Models\Message::factory()->count(10)->create()
```

This is assuming you have the message model in that directory.  Just substitute App\Models with whatever directory it's in.